# inserting multiple record at once

Tags: php

Hello I have a form like below:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset><legend>Products List</legend>
    <ul>
    <li><input type='hidden' name='product[]' value='1'/>Product 1</li>
    <li><input type='hidden' name='product[]' value='2'/>Product 2</li>
    <li><input type='hidden' name='product[]' value='3'/>Product 3</li>
    <li><input type='hidden' name='product[]' value='4'/>Product 4</li>
    <li><input type='hidden' name='product[]' value='5'/>Product 5</li>
    </ul>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to know how to insert all the product id in the hidden field value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you intend to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php  
foreach($_POST['product'] as $key=>$val)
{ 
  $product_id = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (id,product_id) VALUES (NULL,'".$product_id."')";
  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Do not do this, it will make your application vulnerable to SQL injection. Use PDO and prepared statements instead.

Comment: @igorw: now it SQL injection free.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your post isn't very clear. Do you mean something like this?

```
$product = range(1, 5);
foreach($product as $prod)
{
    echo "<li><input type='hidden' name='product[]' value='" . $prod . "'/>Product " . $prod . "</li>";
}
```

?

EDIT: Or do you mean how to inesrt them all at once into a Database?!

Comment: Why do you use hidden fields anyway? It is safer to store them in a session. This way they can't be changed on posting.